# Firestore transaction stuck on the `await t.get` only on iOS in Flutter (works on Android)

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I don't understand why my transaction seems to lock my app (no exception is thrown).

This code works nicely on Android though.

(Btw, it sounds like all transaction based code suffers from the same issue on iOS but work on Android).

My code is as follows:

```dart
  /// Suspend the ad to make it offline or throw an error if it does not exist or if an error occured
  Future<void> transactionStoreSetOffline() async {
    final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    return fs.runTransaction((t) async {
      /// Reads the ad document
      final doc = await t.get(fs.collection("ads").doc(id));
      // .get();

      // if (!doc.exists) throw Exception("Ad does not exist");

      t.update(doc.reference, {
        "suspended": true,
        "clearedForSale": false,
      });
    });
  }
```

[UPDATE 1] Here is the no-transaction iOS version that works OK:

```dart
  /// Suspend the ad to make it offline or throw an error if it does not exist or if an error occured
  Future<void> transactionStoreSetOffline() async {
    final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      final ref = fs.collection(collectionName).doc(id);

      return ref.update({
        "suspended": true,
        "clearedForSale": false,
      });
    }

    return fs.runTransaction((t) async {
      /// Reads the ad document
      final doc = await t.get(fs.collection(collectionName).doc(id));
      // .get();

      // if (!doc.exists) throw Exception("Ad does not exist");

      t.update(doc.reference, {
        "suspended": true,
        "clearedForSale": false,
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From this link [cloud_firestore plugin versions](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog)

> v 4.12.1 : FIX(firestore,ios): fix freeze when doing a get in transactions when auth is also installed (#11773). (180c0918)
> FIX(firestore,android): fix hot reload freezing the app on Android (#11776). (bd1ab457)

I had to bump my plug-in version as the team did fix the issue in v4.12.1.